# Do not create object if old object with same attribute is associated to same current object's associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I've has_many: :through association with tables Foo, FooBar and Bar. Here is their implementation:

```rb
Class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :foo_bars, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bars, through: :foo_bars
end

Class FooBar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end

Class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :foo_bars, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :foos, through: :foo_bars
end
```

Example:

```rb
bar = Bar.create(name: "bar")
bar.foos << Foo.create(name: "foo")
foo.bars has bar object with name "bar"
bar.foos has foo object with name "foo"
```

and

```rb
FooBar.first object has foo_id: 1, bar_id: 1
```

Let's create a new Bar object

```
bar2 = Bar.create(name: "bar2")
```

now we have two bar objects

What I want to do is, I do not want to create a new foo object if foo.name = "foo"
and it is being associated with bar with name "bar" because bar has already foo with "foo".
But I want to create foo object if foo.name = "foo"
and it is being associated with bar2 object
because bar2.foos does not have foo with name "foo"

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what association you want it on since all those foobars are hard to parse. But it sounds like you want to [validate uniqueness](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) based on a scope which can be done by adding the following line to the model you want to be unique

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :parent_id
```

To create a database constraint to prevent possible violations of a uniqueness validation using the :scope option, you must create a unique index on both columns in your database. Depending on what database you are using, you'll want to check either [the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) for more details about multiple column indexes or [the PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) for examples of unique constraints that refer to a group of columns (also sourced from the rails guide on validating uniqueness).

Comment: Not sure 100% if that's a correct answer, but assuming it is: without accompanying DB index you'll end up with elements violating this uniqueness rule.

Comment: @Grzegorz I've updated the answer to note this. IF OP identifies which DB he's using, then I'll update my answer to provide the specifics on how to implement it.